# Imagemagick convert and compose batch of files

Tags: imagemagick, batch-processing, imagemagick-convert

I am trying to make a fast convert of a batch of files like this:

```
convert ./src/*.png -set filename: '%t' -gravity West -draw 'image over 0,0 424,600 "./panel.png"' ./dest/%[filename:].png
```

which is pretty similar to COMPOSITE:

```
convert ./src/*.png ./panel.png -set filename: '%t' -gravity +0+0 -composite ./dest/%[filename:].png
```

except the last one is not working and just making one first crappy-looking file.
Looks like it's bug?

Does anybody know how to make it more correct with -composite?
for|awk|ls|find for each file in shell is not acceptable - because that is slower than the first example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Read in the list of files,
- set their output filenames,
- include the IM special image placeholder "null:",
- read in your overlay image,
- optionally, set the geometry,
- and composite that overlay onto all the other images with "-layers composite".

That `null:` separates the original input file list from the overlay image so ImageMagick knows where in the stack you want to start doing the composite.

Try something like this (one step per line for readability):

```
convert ./src/*.png \
    -set filename: '%t' \
    null: \
    ./panel.png \
    -layers composite ./dest/%[filename:].png
```

Comment: Yes, works like 


`convert ./src/*.png -set filename: '%t' null: ./panel.png -geometry +0+0 -layers composite ./dest/%[filename:].png`


Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

> Looks like it's bug?

Not a bug. Your second command is telling ImageMagick to consume all files matched into an image stack, and composite it as one.

You can attempt the same solution with the `mogrify` utility, but I believe it would be *way* simpler if you expand the bash script with a single `for` loop.

```sh
for f in $(ls src/*.png)
do
   dest=$(basename $f);
   convert "$f" ./panel.png -gravity West -composite "./dest/$dest"
done
```

Comment: It takes more time :(

Comment: Use [Gnu Parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) if you need to save time.

Answer (score 2):

You could use Imagemagick mogrify command. See http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/basics/#mogrify and http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/basics/#mogrify_compose

```
cd to input directory
mogrify -format png -path ./dest -gravity West -draw 'image over 0,0 424,600 "./panel.png"' *.png
```

Comment: yes, but in that case its pretty same like convert because of -path param
and -composite is faster